# Given $u$ subharmonic, show that $u^p$ subharmonic for $p\geq 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

**Exercise**

I'm currently reading through *Holomorphic Functions and Integral Representations in Several Complex Variables* by R. Michael Range, and I've been tasked with the following (Exercise II.4.4):

> Let $u$ be subharmonic on $D\subseteq\mathbb{C}$. Show that $u^p$ is subharmonic for $p\geq 1$.

There is also a hint:

> Hint: Use Hölder's inequality.

**My Thoughts**

I feel like I can prove this if I'm given that $u$ is nonnegative on $D$, since Hölder's inequality shows
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}|u(z_0+\rho e^{it})|\,dt\leq\left(\int_{0}^{2\pi}|u(z_0+\rho e^{it})|^{p}\,dt\right)^{1/p}
$$
for some fixed $z_0\in D$ and $\rho>0$ small enough that $B(z_0,\rho)\subseteq D$, and if I'm given $u\geq 0$ on $D$, then $|u|=u$ and combining the above equation with the sub-mean-value property of $u$ should show the result.

Also I feel like if I'm merely given $u$ continuous I could do some local arguments of this sort to show the result, but I'm not even given that.

I had a moment of weakness and looked on the internet to see I could find this proven somewhere, but every source I could find only proved it given $u\geq 0$ on the domain. This makes think that the statement might even be true unless given this extra hypothesis.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What does $u^p$ even mean for negative $u$?

Comment: @mf I don't readily see a problem with defining $u^p$ for negative $u$. There would be a potential issue for $p\in (0,1)$, but we're assuming $p\geq 1$. What is the issue you're seeing?

Comment: How do you interpret $(-1)^{5/2}$ for example? Or even more problematic: $(-1)^\pi$. (Subharmonic functions are usually real valued.)

Comment: @mrf ah I see the issue now. Yes we are assuming u is real-valued (or possibly $-\infty$). Do you think the author meant to assume $u\geq 0$?

Comment: I would think so.

Comment: @mrf Thank you so much for your help. Is there any way to mark this question as resolved even though there is no answer posted?

Comment: There. Now you can mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense to allow $u$ to attain negative values. What is $(-1)^{5/2}$ or $(-1)^{\pi}$ supposed to mean? (Subharmonic functions are real-valued.)

Most likely the author forgot to add the assumption that $u\ge 0$.